# How can I extract the entire columns that its column name match a certain pattern of a CSV file?

Tags: text-processing, csv

I am not too familiar with Unix and am working on a very large CSV file right now.

Here is an example:

```
ABC1,ABC2,ABC3,DDD,EEE,FFF
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

How can I extract all columns that start with `ABC`?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to indicate what you already tried and where you ran into problems. That way contributors can understand what tools you have available/are familiar with, and you can avoid receiving proposed solutions that you already know won't work.

Comment: When you say "Unix" do you actually mean Unix or are you really using Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following `awk` program will do. Store it in a file, e.g. `extract.awk`:

```c
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS=OFS=","}

FNR==1 {
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    if (index($i,startstr)==1) cols[++ncol]=i;
  }
}

{ for (j=1;j<=ncol;j++) printf("%s%s",$(cols[j]),j==ncol?ORS:OFS) }
```

You would then call it as

```
~$ awk -f extract.awk -v startstr="ABC" input.csv
ABC1,ABC2,ABC3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

where you define the string you are looking for in the variable `startstr`.

This will first set the input and output field separators to `,`.

- In the first (header) line it will check if any column names start with your search string, which is stored in the variable `startstr`. If so, the column number will be added to an array `cols` of "columns to print".
- For each line (including the first), it will then print the value of all columns stored in `cols`, followed by either the field separator or the record separator (defaults to newline) if it is the last column to print.

Note that we use a literal string match using the `index()` function of `awk` rather than a regular-expression based match, in case your actual search string contains characters that are special in the context of regular expressions. If you must use a regular-expression base search, change the

```c
if (index($i,startstr)==1) cols[++ncol]=i;
```

to

```c
if ($i ~ startstr) cols[++ncol]=i
```

but beware that all characters in `startstr` are then subject to interpretation as regular expression tokens, which can lead to unexpected behavior if one is not careful. For the example you mentioned, `startstr` would be `^ABC`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with awk, but it's easier in perl because of perl's array slice feature.  In awk, you'd have to iterate over the wanted array to get the same result.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
my @wanted;   # array to hold the indices we want to print

while(<>) {
  chomp;

  # split the input line into array @F, using commas as the delimiter.
  my @F = split /,/;

  if ($. == 1) {  # process the first line (the headers)
    # if a header matches the regex, add it to @wanted
    foreach my $i (0 .. $#F) {
      push @wanted, $i if $F[$i] =~ m/^abc/i;
    };
  };

  # print the columns of @F whose indices are listed in @wanted
  print join(",", @F[@wanted]), "\n";
}
```

Save as, e.g., `abc.pl` and make executable with `chmod +x abc.pl`, then run like so:

```
$ ./abc.pl input.csv
ABC1,ABC2,ABC3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

How this works:

- The `foreach` loop adds the index number of each field matching `/abc/` (case-insensitive) to the `@wanted` array
- with the sample input given, `@wanted` ends up containing `0`, `1`, and `2`.
- The `@F[@wanted]` as used in the `print join()` statement is effectively the same as `@F[0,1,2]` (i.e. elements `0`, `1`, and `2` of `@F`).  These elements are joined with comma characters and printed.

---

###### Extra Stuff:

The `if ($. == 1) {...}` block using `foreach` could be re-written to use perl's `grep` function.  The entire block could be replaced with just one line:

```
   @wanted = grep($F[$_] =~ m/^abc/i, keys @F) if ($. == 1);
```

Some would say this is more idiomatically perl.  I disagree - perl has both `foreach` and `grep` (and `map` and `join` and many other functions & operators that process arrays or lists), and using **any** of them is "idiomatic perl".

Note: using `keys` on an indexed array requires a version of perl newer than or equal to v5.12, which was released in 2010.   Prior to that, `keys` only worked  on hash arrays.

Also, the entire script could be condensed into a one-liner with only two statements:

```
$ perl -F, -lne '@wanted = grep($F[$_] =~ m/^abc/i, keys @F) if ($. == 1);
                 print join(",", @F[@wanted]);' input.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

Very straightforward using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), whose [cut](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs.html#cut) has an option for regex matching column names:

```
$ mlr --csv cut -r -f '^ABC' input.csv
ABC1,ABC2,ABC3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
flds=$(< file head -n 1 | tr ',' '\n' | grep -ne '^ABC' | cut -d: -f1 | paste -sd, -)

cut -d, -f"${flds}" file

ABC1,ABC2,ABC3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

We do in a two-step process, wherein we first extract the header and from that get the field numbers of fields that begin with ABC.

Next , armed with this info we plug it in a cut command to extract these fields from the whole file.